# JPA/Hibernate: Problems with one join table for two different entities on same join columns

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm glad that this community exists, it helped me out several times in the past for different little problems.
But now I have a bigger problem and spent almost two days to find answers and solutions, but unfortunately, I found nothing about it.
Perhaps someone can help and had a similar problem before.

I'll try to explain:
I want to build a kind of tree structure with items.
One item can have several child items (for example article (parent) and its ingredients (child's)). These child items can have again several children's and so on. But one item can also have one or more processes (for example like cooking). Processes don't need to be in a tree structure like items.
So I build a model which consists of table Item, table ItemResource and table Process. Each table has a composite primary key. The table ItemResource should be the join table for the other tables, so it will keep the reference to the parent items and reference to concrete item OR reference to process.
Therefore it has an attribute resourceType in PK, so we can see if it is a resource to item OR a resource to process.
My approach (code) looks like this:

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="Item")
public class Item 
{

    @Getter @Setter
    @EmbeddedId
    private ItemIdPK id;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="name", length=50)
    @Size(max=50)
    private String name;


    @Getter @Setter
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentItem")
    private List<ItemResource> itemResources = new ArrayList<ItemResource>();

}

@Embeddable
public class ItemIdPK implements Serializable 
{

    public ItemIdPK() {

    }

    public ItemIdPK(String itemNumber, short mandator) {
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
        this.mandator = mandator;
    }

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="itemNumber", length=31)
    @Size(max=31)
    private String itemNumber;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="mandator")
    @Size(max=2)
    private short mandator;

}



@Entity
@Table(name="ItemResource")
public class ItemResource 
{   

    @Getter @Setter
    @EmbeddedId
    private ItemResourceIdPK id;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="quantity")
    private BigDecimal quantity;    //extra column in join table


    @Getter @Setter
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "refItemNumber", referencedColumnName="itemNumber", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "mandator", referencedColumnName="mandator", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Item parentItem;


    @Getter @Setter
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "resourceNumber", referencedColumnName="itemNumber", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "mandator", referencedColumnName="mandator", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Item item;


    @Getter @Setter
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "resourceNumber", referencedColumnName="processNumber", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "mandator", referencedColumnName="mandator", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private Process process;

}

@Embeddable
public class ItemResourceIdPK implements Serializable 
{

    public ItemResourceIdPK() {

    }

    public ItemResourceIdPK(String resourceNumber, short mandator, String refItemNumber, ResourceType resourceType) {
        this.resourceNumber = resourceNumber;
        this.mandator = mandator;
        this.refItemNumber = refItemNumber;
        this.resourceType = resourceType;
    }

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="refItemNumber", length=31)    // --> reference for parent item
    @Size(max=31)
    private String refItemNumber;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="resourceNumber", length=31)       // --> itemNumber or processNumber
    @Size(max=31)
    private String resourceNumber;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="mandator")
    @Size(max=2)
    private short mandator;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="resourceType", length=3)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ResourceType resourceType;


    public enum ResourceType {
        MA,     //first type (for items)
        AG;     //second type (for processes)

        public String value() {
            return name();
        }

        public static ResourceType fromValue(String v) {
            return valueOf(v);
        }
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="Process")
public class Process 
{

    @Getter @Setter
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProcessIdPK id;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="processName", length=50)
    @Size(max=50)
    private String processName;


    public Process() {

    }

    public Process(String processName) {
        super();
        this.processName = processName;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class ProcessIdPK implements Serializable 
{   
    public ProcessIdPK() {

    }

    public ProcessIdPK(String processNumber, short mandator) {
        this.processNumber = processNumber;
        this.mandator = mandator;
    }

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="processNumber", length=31)
    @Size(max=31)
    private String processNumber;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Column(name="mandator")
    @Size(max=2)
    private short mandator;

}
```

The problem/result:
The ddl auto-generation did everything well in the database, except two foreign key constraints in ItemResource table which avoid inserting sets, if resourceNumber Id is not present in Item table OR Process table, even if I have the different resourceType to differ them in PK.
The second problem then is, that while testing it with some data there is an entity not found exception for table Process, even if I want to load only items (I think because of eager loading).
But how can I avoid these problems? Is it not possible with JPA? Because from the logical side in the database it has to be ok.
What could I change? The database model is given from customer and should not be changed.

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Bergerjung

P.S.: Sorry, perhaps it's not really an JPA problem, except the unwanted foreign key constraints, which I can remove after generation and then set auto update to false. 
Perhaps it is simply a loading problem and there is any solution  (resourceType condition for eager loaded (because OneToOne) process OR item). Is there existing anything for this?

Comment: on the margin: are You sure must have composite primary key? BTW ProcessIdPK  don't have isEqual, hashcode, compareTo etc...

Comment: Hi Jacek, yes, unfortunaltely I must have composite primary keys, because it is given by customer. So this makes it a little bit more different. And I also have isEqual and hashCode methods (in all embedded PK classes) but I shortened it for this post here.

Comment: Hi everybody, I edited my question again, please see P.S., I think it just a loading problem for eager loaded OneToOne entities...